# Using rendered with JSF

Tags: jsf

How does `rendered` work? It hides `h:form` content completely and does not show it if `expression.list` is not empty.

```
<h:form id="stackForm" rendered="#{not empty expression.list}"> 
   <p:orderList  id="stack" value="#{expression.list}"...
   ...
```

Comment: In the future, try to ask a question about X (the concrete functional requirement) instead of Y (whatever you thought to be the right solution to X). See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't hide it - it doesn't render it at all, if `rendered` condition evaluates to `false`. In your case, if `#{expression.list}` is empty, form will not be rendered. Or, when `rendered` is translated to plain English, read it as *Render the form if `expression.list` is not empty*.

Comment: Well, I understand what it mean. The question is - if it does not render it at all then will not other element, which contains `update="stack"`, work properly?